# Is aviation slowly dying as of 2019

Tags: general-aviation

This debate first started a decade ago but I want to modernize it.

The reasons people wanted to be pilots. (I cant find a single reason why someone would want to become an ATC)

- They watched Top Gun etc. and decided to be pilots.
- Their grandparents were WW2 Veterans which fascinated them with war stories.
- They simply loved seeing planes that flew above their homes.
- They liked the WW2 pilot stories on the school.

Problems these days.

- Aviation movies are getting rarer and rarer and the millenials love watching nothing other than Ninja's Fortnite streams.
- There isnt anyone to fascinate the kids with their war stories.
- Since people are doing nothing but sitting on PC's and playing Fortnite with noise cancelling headphones they dont even see planes.
- Since social media stories are better than the history lessons they get fascinated only by the success stories of Elon Musk etc.
- All of this cumulated with the ever increasing pilot school fees and lack of interest of aviation where people act like animal herds where they will do their best to stay in a group like a dog that will never leave their owner kills the indivuality where the group leader is the role model for everyone else.

The final hypothetis is: Since nobody will want to become pilots this industry will be taken by the 1 pilot Artifical Intelligence planes (Altough the transocean hyperloop will balance) and the general aviation (Especailly Private Aviation with 100 percent of self flying pilots will die) will suffer trendmeous failures plus there are "rumours" of ATC being taken over by AI and humans only interfering in emergencies

I know this question seems like an some other broad and opinion based question but I think the next paragraphs can solve this problem.

Long story short. **What I really want to find is an answer that includes some charts and infographics that will show the rate of people getting pilot certificates over the years.**

Comment: This question is very broad and opinion based, I can't see it having good answers.

Comment: That's why they're making Top Gun 2.

Comment: The original US astronauts insisted on a window being installed on the first capsules. That was so they could pretend, to themselves, they were pilots not passengers.

Comment: I can't see a single reason why someone would want to be an accountant but the accounting sector isn't going anywhere.

Comment: @Ben so I guesss some "crazy" people that loves stressing themselves over "boring" jobs that are nothing more than sitting all day solving questions exist.

Comment: Your question made me laugh. I get why you're saying what you're saying... But you didn't have to generalize and throw everyone (I'm assuming this is directed at the latest generation) in the same lazy bucket because all _you_ see is video games and headphones. You also make some claims about interest waning over the whole world (aviation is global). I'd like to see info graphics about this, too. From you. - 1

Comment: @Pheric even if we say birth dates are staying stable through the USA (Altough states are different in rate) the number of people are slowly decreasing. Altough this generation (15 to 20 year olds) are doing some fine stuff the next gen (0 to 15 year olds) that have enough intellect to play Fortnite (I am joking plus it became a disease so not so bad). The mass automation will probably crash so many industries which will make the people spend a little bit more money on basic needs (Unless people  have gold deposit plans like me) and from little bit interest people to dreamers will get hurt.

Comment: @JonathanIrons nobody knows any of that for sure, because it's not that bad yet. The best we can do is trend what it is today and pretend that the trend will hold true, which it probably won't. And don't forget that trends like fortnite are how life is. When you were a child, you probably played games and such too, but you didn't stop dreaming and you grew up (probably). Even if becoming a pilot isn't as popular as it once was, it might only take a large event to spark that interest in people again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the information that you are looking for can be found in this [AOPA Report.](http://download.aopa.org/hr/Report_on_General_Aviation_Trends.pdf)  Basically aviation is on a rebound.  The report compares available data from 2015 to 2017 and the amount of pilot certificates being issued in the Private, Commercial, CFI, and Instrument ratings all increased.

A side note about your comments on there being less aviation movies and references in Pop Culture.  There are actually a ton of very good YouTube channels out there on Aviation and have inspired many (myself included) to become pilots.

Comment: thanks for sending me the tottally objective AOPA report and good luck in your future endavaours plus it makes me happy to see people that does something other than playinf Fortnite.

Answer (score 2):

Not according to Boeing.  They see a need for over 40,000+ new aircraft over the next 20 years.

Ranting aside, it might be a good idea to think about why someone would want to be a
PROFESSIONAL pilot.  Maybe a little more than movies and grandpa's stories.  Maybe a little more like a commitment to a career.

If you are at a computer and proficient enough to ask the question, references and resources are only a click away on another tab.

For the younger, R/C flying offers a huge head start in learning the fundamentals of flight.
There are also many flying schools geared towards training future airline pilots.

Yes, automation is making inroads in control of aircraft, and it will be a challenge for the engineers and pilots to decide how much is actually needed.